# Does getStaticProps fetch data every time I get back same page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using routes to get page ex. `page/[id].js` and show data for that id only. So will it refetch data every time I visit this page? ex. going to the next page through a link on this page and pressed back to get back to this page. Like it happens in React.js data fetching using `DidComponentMount` it fetches every time it mounts, even when you get back already visited the page.

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://.../data/${context.params.id}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return {
        props: { data }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getStaticProps` runs on the server at build time, it doesn't run on every request to the page. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-with-data for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getStaticProps` inside our pages (not inside components) tells next.js that current page will be statically generated. The code executed in `getStaticProps` will not be included in the code bundle that sent back to the client.

The idea of `getStatisProps` you pre-generate the page during build time. That means all the `HTML` code and data are prepared in advance. Since pages are prebuilt, when we deploy them they can get cached by the server so incoming requests can be served instantly. So when pages are served, they are not empty, they are pre-populated with content.

if you run `npm run build`, visit `.next/server/` directory and you will see the pre-generated HTML files.

What happens if data changes frequently. pre-generated pages are great if you are building something fully static. If you are rendering a blog post whose data does not change, it is a good idea to pre-generate the page.

Each time you add new data to your statically generated page, in order to see the change, you have to rebuild your project again. But next.js solves this with `incremental static generation`. With this, your page continuously gets updated without redeploying your app. You just tell next.js that you want your page to get pre-generated after each request at most x seconds. Regenerated page will replace the old page. So you can have ongoing pregenerating for incoming requests. To do so, you just add `revalidate` property:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
      const res = await fetch(`https://.../data/${context.params.id}`)
      const data = await res.json()
      return {
        props: { data }
      },
      // time in seconds
      // this tells if last generated page was more than 60 seconds ago, pregenerate it
      revalidate: 60
    }
```

If you do not add `revalidate` property, your prebuild HTML page will be served from the cache

Comment: thank you soo much telling me about revalidate. but from this new question is that will user see updated page every 60 second (if i update it or i dont) will it reqest new data every 60 sec. if so then that will be inefficient as users internet data will be consumed every 60 sec to fetch updated data.

Comment: @HarshendraPrajapati , that is not my understanding; it won't make a request every 60 seconds, but any requests made after 60 seconds will cause the page to be regenerated (instead of using the cached statically generated results). So the page is regenerated after 60 seconds only WHEN a request is made.

Comment: @Yilmaz, I think there is a typo in your answer. `revalidate: 60` should be inside the brace above it so that it is part of the returned object.

Comment: @Yilmaz On my local I do not see mypage.html but mypage.js inside .next/server/. Also when I open that page in browser I do not a request for a document mypage but I see for a json and js file. What could be wrong?
mypage is a static route and I am using getStaticProps with revalidate: 100 * 10

Comment: what next.js version?